# Find out whether web app or server is compromised

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache2

I'm an rather experienced web developer and have Plesk Onyx running on my dedicated server. It features 2FA via Google Authenticator. Inside Plesk, I added multiple WordPress-based webpages of mine and friends of mine. All of these WordPress installations are securely installed by Plesk and hardened access to by moving the admin area, globally disabling comments, 2FA, and so on.

Now a few days ago, a friend told me he was seeing massive ads on my webpage. Since the server also yields my company's page, that is perhaps something to take serious - so did I. However, I couldn't reproduce the ads or the pop ups, etc. - at all -, neither on my Windows machines (10 and Server 2016), nor on any mobile or laptop device. Yesterday, I was viewing my webpage with a friend of mine (desktop PC). And all of a sudden, ads are shown up when he clicks links in my WP menu and stuff like this. Very pushy, very much, absolutely... unacceptable.

I introduced myself as rather experienced web developer. However, I don't know how to tackle this. Whether my server was actually hacked or compromised, some WordPress plugin is messing up with ads (however, friend found problems on multiple sites that are not using the same plugins), or whatever. I think Plesk and WP are both strong and shouldn't be compromised that easy. Besides, I didn't notice any further.

How to tackle this?

Comment: This could be something that your ISP is introducing. In the UK, a few years ago, one of the big ISPs "filtered" out ads from web sites and replaced them with their own.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -2):

Did you try **Revisium Antivirus** to scan your websites? It is available on Plesk extensions. I had a similar issue and Revisium Antivirus found all the files that were infected.

Also, check your friend's PC (web browser) for malware. There is some malware (hidden software) which can run adds or add strange links to your website. So, in that case, there is nothing to do with your server or websites.